# Can I purify polyhydroxyalkanoates by heating the cells extensively?

Tags: lab-techniques, biotechnology, purification

Traditional methods of purifying polyhydroxyalkanoates (PHAs) and other bioplastics made by bacteria involve washing the cells with harsh chemicals or strong bases.I'm interested in maintaining the spatial position of the PHA globules relative to one another. Therefore, I'm hypothesizing that *by heating these cells extensively, I can lyse/degrade the cellular matter and be left with only PHAs*, especially given that some PHAs have melting points up to 180 degrees.

**Is this approach to purifying PHAs plausible? Has it ever been done?**